# get weather data from the yahoo weather API?

Tags: api

I have a little problem with the Yahoo Weather API, when I make a request to receive weather data for the city of Paris ('client ID' and'secret client' filled in the Authorization section of postman.)the answer to my request is not what I expected and I would like to know if there was anything missing to receive a correct answer to the request? thank you in advance to those who will take time to help me

Comment: Maybe would be good to add what response you are expecting, also you could read from here: https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/  that they are retiring their API (asuming that is the API you are after) and if you want to carry on using it you would need to email them to get credentials.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. if I understand, they will remove their api or I just need to send them an email to continue to use it because it is this api I need for a school project and I am just starting to use the api

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use telnet (google it). You don't have to program, but it allows you to send the same request you send from your code to debug it. If succeeded you normally copy paste it to you JavaScript code with all the parameters you found out working there.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but 'Postman' also allow to receive error message codes from requests, is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi, postman is..... yes.. but I didn't know you use it since you did not put an example and telnet is kinda of built in your computer :) Yes, that I mean.

Comment: That's right, I should have set an example for him. In the meantime I have found a simpler way to use the API in public mode without Oauth (but no longer available from January 3rd I think)